# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined ONn Datatables

Tags: json, ajax, datatables

I have code like this

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                                      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
                                    ];
                while (dateStart <= dateEnd) {
                    dateLoop.push({name : monthNames[dateStart.getMonth()] + ' ' +  dateStart.getFullYear() });
                    var newDate = dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getMonth() + 1);
                    dateStart.setMonth(dateStart.getMonth() + 1);
                }
var jsonArray = {"Columns":dateLoop};
                var columnArray = jsonArray['Columns']; 
                var titleArray = [];
                var title = {};
                title['title'] = "Buyer";
                titleArray.push(title);

                var i = 0;
                for ( 
                var j = 0; j < columnArray.length; j++) {
                    var temp2 = {};
                    temp2['title'] = columnArray[i]["name"];
                    titleArray.push(temp2);
                    i = i + 1;
                };
```

That code i use to add column on Datatables

```
$('#del-date').DataTable({ 
                    "filter": false,
                    "destroy": true,
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "columns": titleArray,
                    "ajax":{
                        url : host+'qty/'+oderby+'?buyer='+buyer+'&dari='+begin+'&sampai='+end,
                        error: function(){  // error handling
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    }
                }).draw();
```

First i submit my filter is button, is work fine and show data i want, but when i change filter is show error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

How to fix it?? Sorry my bad langaunge. I relly stuck on this code

UPDATE : This screen shoot i get error

[image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined]

UPDATE SOLVED!!!! i change into code like this :

```
$.ajax({
                    "url": host+'qty/'+oderby+'?buyer='+buyer+'&dari='+begin+'&sampai='+end,
                    "success": function(json) {
                        var tableHeaders;
                        $.each(json.columns, function(i, val){
                            tableHeaders += "<th>" + val + "</th>";
                        });

                        $("#tableDiv").empty();
                        $("#tableDiv").append('<table id="displayTable" class="dataTable table table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead><tr>' + tableHeaders + '</tr></thead></table>');
                        //$("#tableDiv").find("table thead tr").append(tableHeaders);  

                        $('#displayTable').dataTable(json);
                    },
                    "dataType": "json"
                });
```

And i'm use controller and mysql to create json. Problem solve.

Comment: Is it possible to create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @AneeshSivaraman : It cant i use mysql for this

Answer (score 2):

This happened when the number of titleArray passed to columns ("columns": titleArray) is less than the number of columns your table (tableHeaders) has.